# App cannot be installed from the play store

Tags: android, google-play-console, androidpublisher

After implementing the zoom android sdk, app size increased and hence following block was added in the build.gradle.
splits{
abi{
enable true
include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
universalApk true
}
}
packagingOptions {
jniLibs {
useLegacyPackaging true
}

Bundle was published to the google play console. Installation of the app from playstore gives this error.[image: Playstore error]
Is there a way to find the reason for failure or find the error? If Apk is downloaded from the app bundle explorer(google play console), it installs and works.
All the previous versions worked.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to clear data of Google play store app and try installing the app again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it didn't work. Tried with 4 different devices and same error everywhere.

Comment: I would recommend you reach out to Play developer support. Also consider including the logcat during the installation that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you see any problem using the split apks and legacy packaging? Using in the build.gradle? splits{ abi{ enable true include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a" universalApk true } } packagingOptions { jniLibs { useLegacyPackaging true }